# Список установленных программ + активное окно

Tags: c#, winforms

Собственно в чем задумка: при запуске пользователь отмечает нужные программы (из списка установленных), после этого во время работы с другими программами, приложение получает активное окно и проверяет, есть ли в оно в этом списке. Суть в том, что получая список установленных программ из реестра, мы получаем только название, установочный путь и тд, а при считывании активного окна - его заголовок и дескриптор. По сути, с первой и второй функции данные получаются разные и отслеживать по ним никак не получится. Как тогда можно получить равнозначные данные о ПО, которое установлено и ПО, которое запущено?

Список установленных программ:

```
private void GetInstalledSoftware()
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    string SoftwareKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey))
    {
        foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (sk.GetValue("DisplayName") != null)
                    {
                        items.Add(sk.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString());
                        items.Add(CheckValue(sk.GetValue("DisplayVersion")));
                        items.Add(CheckValue(sk.GetValue("Publisher")));
                        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(items.ToArray()));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
            items.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Активное окно:

```
private void GetActiveWindow()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    int handle = 0;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);

    handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        label10.Text = Buff.ToString();
        label11.Text = handle.ToString();
    }
}
```

`GetForegroundWindow` и `GetWindowText`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetForegroundWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
```

Comment: Думаю, имеет смысл дополнить свой вопрос наработками, дабы внести ясность в суть вопроса.

Comment: @DenisBubnov дополнил

Comment: Что значит *Как все это связать?*? Что Вы хотите видеть в результате?

Comment: Снова не правильно выразился, вопрос поправил. По сути, с первой и второй функции данные получаются разные и отслеживать по ним никак не получится. Как тогда можно получить равнозначные данные о ПО, которое установлено и ПО, которое запущено?

Comment: Вот теперь вопрос стал понятен. Вы пишете: *с первой и второй функции данные получаются разные* - значит связать эти данные по чему-то общему нельзя. Нужно искать что-то общее. Если методы не большие, то добавьте `GetForegroundWindow` и `GetWindowText` в вопрос.

Comment: А случайно ` handle = GetForegroundWindow();` и `sk.Handle.DangerousGetHandle()` - это не одно и то же будет? Если да, то напишу ответ. `sk.Handle.DangerousGetHandle()` - внутри блока `try` добавьте

Comment: Нет, `sk.Handle` в try выдает `Microsoft.Win32.SafeHadles.SafeRegistryHandle

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53379/discussion-between-denis-bubnov-and-g431k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Понадобится сам процесс, чтобы получить его дескриптор. По имени будем получать информацию о процессе, если он запущен - информация есть, если нет информации - процесс не запущен. Добавить следующий код внутри блока `try`:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(skName);
if (processes.Length > 0)
{
    var handle = processes[0].MainWindowHandle ;
    items.Add(handle.ToInt32().ToString());
}
else
{
    items.Add(string.Empty);
}
```

Таким образом Вы будете выводить дескриптор процесса, который будет соответствовать дескриптору, который возвращается из метода `GetForegroundWindow()`. *Но не все приложения будут содержать дескриптор процесса, его будут содержать только запущенные приложения.*

Также можно брать *«ИД процесса»* - он совпадают со значением *«ИД процесса»* из диспетчера задач, а также можно брать `Handle`.